# Jquery each replace innerHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, each

`Jquery`
I am trying to change the inner text on multiple `td` element which I believe should look something like this although `this` does not appear to be a jquery object when I am debugging (I could be wrong).

What is the correct way this should be done?

```
$('.leg-number').each(function () {
        this.html('foo');
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the docs for [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). `this` is a DOM Html Element node, not a jQuery object reference. You can either convert it back to jQuery or use `innerHTML` directly.

```
$(this).html('foo');
```

or

```
this.innerHTML = 'foo';
```

The docs show using `$(this)` in the examples.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe try this instead:

```
$('.leg-number').html('foo');
```

which is a shorter and more efficient way to achieve your goal. It is just asking jQuery to set the inner html of **every** element with class "leg-number" to "foo" without any explicit iteration. Most of the jQuery methods like `.html()` can work on sets of elements so you don't really need to use `.each()` for simple cases like this.

Now on why your version didn't work: Using `.each()` would work if you wrapped `this` with the jQuery function `$()` so you could use the jQuery methods on it:

```
$('.leg-number').each(function () {
    $(this).html('foo');
});
```

The variable `this` inside of the `.each()` callback is a DOM element and you need `$(this)` to convert it into a jQuery object that wraps this element. See the explanation in the answer by epascarello who explained it before I updated my answer.

Comment: OK, enough screwing around. Other than sour grapes, what's with the downvote?

Comment: @j08691, I don't know why my answer was downvoted. Maybe someone will comment it.

Comment: +1 because your first option is more efficient as the `.each()` isn't needed at all.  I would suggest you explain why the OP's code wouldn't work though.  Correct code + explanation is always better than just code.

Comment: @j08691 "Well by looking at your rep I can see you downvoted me. Why?" How do you know that? He has a -2 from getting a downvote on his answer, casting a downvote would be -1.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for the suggestion. I'll update my answer with some better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
this.html('foo');
```

to:

```
$(this).html('foo');
```

You're attempting to use a jQuery method on a non-jQuery object. This of course assumes that your table cells have the class `.leg-number`.